# Difference in the workload related to data-amount and search option

Tags: database-design, performance, normalization, query-performance

A couple of days ago I was asked why it is necessary to use the first normal form also for separation of names.

We have a table which stores `private customers (Name+Surname;Information)` and `business customers (Companyname;Information)`.

My answer was that first of all it is a bad habit not keeping the values atomic and second the workload for using full-text searches will increase and affect the speed of the results as the amount of data in the database grows. An open end search needs less traffic than a full-text one.

Unfortunately I haven't found data related to the question HOW exactly the speed and efficiency decrease if I am searching for '%whatever%' instead of 'whatever%' or even weirder regular expressions.

Especially related to the scenario if the amount of rows in the table increases.

Can someone provide hard facts related to that?

Comment: You need to be clearer on your table structure. Are the forename and surname components stored as a single string? The "information" part - is that really ; delimited in a single column?

Comment: As shown it is just pretty basic stuff:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
 [NameField1] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [NameField2] [varchar](max) NOT NULL)`


And:

`INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([Kontoname1], [Kontoname2]) VALUES ('Random. Inc', 'Main business Partner');
INSERT [dbo].[Customers] ([Kontoname1], [Kontoname2]) VALUES ('John R. Smith', 'Lives next door')`